# Zookeeper curator watcher not receiving any events

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have been trying to use apache curator for zookeeper, but not able to make progress. All I am looking for is to set a watcher on a zk node and listen to all data changes on that particular node. I wrote a simple program to try out this, but I don't receive any events. Here is my code:

```
CuratorFramework curator = new ZookeeperClient(zkHosts).getConnection();

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        CuratorWatcher curatorWatcher = event -> System.out.println("Watched event: " + event);

        try {
            curator.getChildren().usingWatcher(curatorWatcher).forPath(NODE_PATH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            curator.setData().forPath(NODE_PATH, "randomdata1".getBytes());
            curator.setData().forPath(NODE_PATH, "randomdata2".getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zookeeper, getData() and exists() set data watches. getChildren() sets child watches; see [ZooKeeper Watches](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches) for more details

You should use `curator.getData()` instead of `curator.getChildren()` withinin the first `runAsync()` since you do `setData()` in the second `runAsync()`.

If you want to keep `curator.getChildren()`, then you should add a new child under the `NODE_PATH` for testing

Comment: Thank you! I also realized watches are a one-time event, so I had set more watches for continuous notification.